# Android ListView repeating modified list items

Tags: android, listview, recycle

I have a `ListView` with some list items in. Each item has a delete button, which activates another layer on top of the list item to appear with the text that it has been deleted, as see in the delete `onClickListener` in the following code.

These activated `overlays` repeat themselves every so often (like every 8 list items), so I guess android is `recycling` them somehow... 
How can I make it so that this problem doesn't happen anymore?

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final AnnouncementHolderItem holder;
    final View finalView = view;
    Item curr = getItem(i);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new HolderItem(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (HolderItem) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.title.setText(curr.getTitle());
    holder.course.setText(curr.getName());
    holder.marker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Item starred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((LinearLayout) finalView.findViewById(R.id.bottomLayer)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            LinearLayout delete = (LinearLayout)finalView.findViewById(R.id.deleteLayer);
            delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    holder.undelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Reverse of the delete + a toast message
        }
    });
    return finalView;
}
```

And the list item is a `FrameLayout`, with the deleted layer on top (default invisible) and the info about the item below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right: the listview is recycling views.  You need some means of keeping track of which items have been "deleted" outside the control of the listview.  In your case, it sounds like a simple array would do the trick.

Below is an example of code I've used to do the same thing.  In this case, it's a checkbox, where all checkboxes are initially unchecked.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checkbox_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        if (checkedArray[position] == true)
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }
    holder.checkbox.setText((CharSequence) mData.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Allright, so just set it up with a basic MVC system then... Thanks for the answer!